# How to retrieve the cloud probabilities of a region in google's Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am trying to retrieve the sentinel-2 cloud probabilities for a specific part (inside a polygon) of specific images (I use Python, and the ee and gee packages). So first I select an image, then I clip the image according to a geometry, and then I want the cloud probabilities of the pixels within said geometry. Just to clarify; I want the cloud probabilities themselves, not any other bands.

I have no issue retrieving for example the mask generated by clipping. But when I try to retrieve the probabilities - for example with GEE's to_numpy function - I always run into an error. I do not fully understand the error or how to solve it:

The error:

```
Image.sampleRectangle: Fully masked pixels / pixels outside of the image footprint when sampling band 'probability' with no default value set. Note that calling sampleRectangle() on an image after ee.Image.clip() may result in a sampling bounding box outside the geometry passed to clip().
```

The code:

```
# select the cloud probabilities for a specific satellite image
ee_img = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY/20210125T105331_20210125T105443_T31UFT')
# define the geometry coords
geometry_mapping = (((613650.5820831617, 5711691.00087215), (613709.8033926972, 5711618.801383249), (613711.0837872773, 5711620.118659208), (613759.3147570328, 5711556.738051765), (613750.2316769781, 5711549.300792044), (613703.1418469574, 5711504.0910918545), (613659.4698438506, 5711465.166184718), (613649.3122671937, 5711462.630475706), (613590.0216766379, 5711542.323225024), (613537.8803668057, 5711620.703080251), (613535.9246722562, 5711623.367081324), (613621.5843250428, 5711683.823054567), (613621.4213715852, 5711684.064812057), (613643.6464778696, 5711699.472129337), (613650.5820831617, 5711691.00087215)),)
# create a polygon to clip the image to the region I am interested in
ee_geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(geometry_mapping, 
                                  proj='epsg:32631', 
                                  evenOdd=False)
# clip the image according to the mask
ee_clip = ee_im.clip(ee_geometry)
# retrieve the result as numpy:
result = geemap.ee_to_numpy(ee_clip)
```

This returns the aforementioned error. Applying getInfo() to the ee_clip suggests the ee_img is indeed clipped (as it is smaller). But for some reason it always gives the error, and I can't make it return an array of the probabilities. The strange thing is that I can return the mask generated by the clip itself. The following code works:

```
ee_mask = ee_clip.mask()
result = geemap.ee_to_numpy(ee_mask)
result.shape
>>> (24, 23, 1)
```

but this only contains an array 1s for the pixels inside the ee_geometry, and 0s for pixels outside the polygon (and ofcourse border pixels) - as expected. This suggests that there is nothing wrong with the polygon I am using. I am guessing I am not applying the mask correctly, or that some information is missing for EE. I have tried various things - though perhaps not correctly - with selecting, unmasking, and updating but to no avail. Can anyone help me bridge the gap?

I tried to retrieve the probabilities using the aforementioned code. I also tried using unmask with the above created mask, and updateMask. I have also tried selecting the probabilities band specifically.